# Fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys in Almofire?

Tags: ios, dictionary, alamofire

Hai I am using Almofire to send Api post requests Where I have to use same parameters with different values.

```
postParameters=[
          "xxx"; "yyy",
          "xxx": "zzz"
]
```

where postParamters are the parameters which I have used for api request.But it shows `duplicate keys`.Can anyone please help me to fix this.I could not use different parameter name.I have to use only `xxx` but different values `yyy` and `zzz`.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary. Could you add more context? What is the post parameter format?

Comment: @Frankenstein  var postParameters:[String:Any]!

Comment: I was asking for the sample post parameters. For eg: {
 "id ": 1,
 "name ": "some name"
}